# Hot Swap Agent doesn't work with Java 8 and Tomcat 8.0.26

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, hotswap

I have a question about hot swap agent. I configured it with java 8 and tomcat 8.0.26 64 bit. When I start server under Eclipse I got some errors:

```
Caused by: compile error: cannot find constructor org.apache.catalina.webresources.FileResource(org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot,java.lang.String,java.io.File,boolean)
```

and

```
Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.NotFoundException: getResource(..) is not found in org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
```

I put more detailed stack trace if it's needed.

I red that hot swap has problems with tomcat 8 to 8.0.23 version, but newer versions should work. I'm using 0.3 version of Hot Swap Agent. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a fix in official repository for Tomcat >8.0.23. This has been fixed after 0.3 release. You have to either downgrade tomcat to 8.0.23 or build last HotswapAgent from https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it when I came to home.

Comment: Ok, I built last hot swap agent from repo and change jar file. Now I don't get this error, looks like hot swap agent starts correctly, but I can't see my changes. But I found another error in log:

Caused by: org.hotswap.agent.javassist.NotFoundException: buildSessionFactory(..) is not found in org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration

Comment: Which Hibernate version have you? (3.x is not supported)

Comment: Yes, you sure, I updated hibernate version to 4.3.5 version and now I don't get an error. It seems as everything should be fine. I don't get any exceptions. But when I make a change in code and save nothing happens... And also there is no changes in log file related with hot swap.
It seems like hot swap is configured properly (I think that because of beginning logs).