# Hot Swap Agent under eclipse - no immediately effects after change

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, hotswap

I have a problem with hot swap agent on java 8u51 under eclipse. I installed DCEVM with same version and configured hot swap agent under eclipse. When I made a change nothing happens (and nothing appears in logs). For me it looks like hot swap is configured properly. I attached my server log file. Contains logs from server start and deploy simple spring MVC app. Maybe something is wrong and it is in log file, but I don't know where (no errors).

[Log file](http://pastebin.com/6nhG3AUZ)

Thanks in advance for help.

Related topic is here:
[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467413/hot-swap-agent-doesnt-work-with-java-8-and-tomcat-8-0-26)

Comment: Look at running processes if you see the correct arguments for "java" process. You should see -XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent=... at least.

Comment: It's a web app so I cannot (or I don't know how to) check this process in windows task manager. But of course I added in tomcat launch configuration as an argument path to hot swap agent:
-XXaltjvm="dcevm" -javaagent:C:\hotswapagent\hotswap-agent.jar

Comment: Ok, finally it works! I added autoHotswap=true to previous line and magically it started working.